# Galaxy Note 4 travel restrictions

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, airport-security, electronic-items

I have a Galaxy Note 4.  I know that the Note 7 is restricted.  Has anyone had trouble getting other phones aboard a plane recently?

Just want to know if I should leave it home.

Answer (score 5):

This quite broad but let's review a few agencies.

1. [India](http://dgca.nic.in/public_notice/public_notices.htm) there's nothing aside from the specific Note 7 ban.
2. [USA](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/) you might be surprised to see there's no mention of the Note 7 in the 2016 SAFOs. What there is the "SAFO 16011, Air Transport Restrictions for Recalled Lithium Batteries and Lithium Battery Powered Devices" -- the Note 7 got banned because it had a safety recall.
3. [EU](https://ad.easa.europa.eu/ad/2017-01), this one is the only newer I am aware of, EASA SIB 2017-01 replaced EASA SIB 2016-14R1 on 2017 February 09 and instead of a specific device it focuses on "damaged, defective or recalled
   lithium batteries or devices" much as SAFO 16011 did.

In short: if your device is powered by a battery which is not damaged, defective or recalled you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

I have completed over 10 trips by plane since October 2016, all with my trusty old Note 4. No problems whatsoever with any airline. I was asked various times what model I had (only in USA) but after clarifying and proving to be a Note 4, everything was ok.

You will not have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I flew to the UK with both the 2 and the 4 no problems either time. 2014-2016